# How to exclude comments from Facebook subscription notifications?

Tags: facebook, facebook-notifications, facebook-subscriptions

The new "subscription" feature of Facebook is clearly valuable. But:

Even though I am only subscribed to one person and expect to only get notified ***once*** when the person posts a new update, I constantly get notifications! Why is that so?

I now noticed and assume that Facebook always notifies me for every single comment from one individual friend of the person I subscribed to!

I don't even know those persons and I don't care and I ***did not*** subscribe to (or like) the individual comment "thread", so I don't understand why I still get notified?!

I checked the "Notification" settings, there is no sub-settings menu for the "subscriptions" feature. Did anyone else notice this and complain to Facebook? I mean I wonder what I'd do if I subscribed to dozens of people then? That would be a complete overload!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default you will see anything from that person that is publicly visible, including public comments.  To turn these off, go to their profile or timeline and find the "Subscribed" button at the top, or hover over their name in one of their posts.  While hovering over the "Subscribed" button, go down to "Comments and Likes" and uncheck it to stop seeing their Comments and Likes in your News Feed.

Comment: Ah thank you very much, I found it indeed! How could I miss that...